# How to make recursive akka stream 'toggleable' from inside class

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a class with endless stream that defined as follows:

```
abstract class StreamWrapper() {

  def doStuff: Future[Unit] = ???

  def recursiveStream(): Unit =
    events.mapAsync(parallelism)(doStuff)
      .runWith(Sink.fold(???))
      .onComplete( 
        actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(delay)(recursiveStream())
                                               // ^-- recursion --^
      )

}
```

I wan't to be able to turn off/on this stream from `doStuff` function (in my case I have a circuit breaker inside, so I want to turn on/off recursiveStream via it's callbacks).

Easiest way to solve this to introduce atomic boolean, check it in `recursiveStream` method and toggle it inside `doStuff`:

```
abstract class StreamWrapper() {

  private val enabled = new AtomicBoolean(true)

  def doStuff: Future[Unit] = ??? // toggle enabled here

  def recursiveStream(): Unit = 
    if (enabled)
      events.mapAsync(parallelism)(doStuff)
        .runWith(Sink.fold(???))
        .onComplete( 
          actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(delay)(recursiveStream())
        )
    else log.info("Stream is currently offline...")

}
```

But it feels like there are may be more idiomatic solution to do it using Scala and/or Akka features. Can you suggest another method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Valve`](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/api/akka-stream-contrib/current/akka/stream/contrib/Valve.html) from the [Akka Streams Contrib project](https://github.com/akka/akka-stream-contrib):

> Materializes into a Future of [ValveSwitch](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/api/akka-stream-contrib/current/akka/stream/contrib/ValveSwitch.html) which provides a the method flip that stops or restarts the flow of elements passing through the stage. As long as the valve is closed it will backpressure.

Examples of its use are found in [`ValveSpec`](https://github.com/akka/akka-stream-contrib/blob/v0.9/contrib/src/test/scala/akka/stream/contrib/ValveSpec.scala).

Comment: Thanks! I can't create new dependencies on current project. But seems like it should not be hard to implement this stage myself. :)

Comment: However, In my case it may not work. Stream runs new stream recursively with delay and it may be tricky to get materialized value of each new Stream. I need to play with this a little bit.